# curl api call failing on platform.sh hook

Tags: bash, curl, deployment

I'm trying to implement a message sending on my platform.sh server. The idea would be to use the existing hooks:deploy: hook in the configuration file to make a bash curl call that would send a message to an api "Deploy completed".

I use a curl snippet that works like a charm on my local machine, though the message is never sent from the server on a new deploy.

I know that the correct interpreter is bash, since the existing example in platform.sh docs is using bash code. Though, it's indicated in the docs that the disk is in read-only mode during this hook, would that be the cause of the issue?

Thanks a lot!

~SPJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I thought it was irrelevant, but French text with accents in the API parameters was causing the issue...

Hope this will help others.

~SPJ

Answer (score 1):

For posterity: also note that this may already exist by default in Platform.sh you can use the webhook integration to get notified of any activity.

```
$ platform integration:add --type=webhook --url=A-URL-THAT-CAN-RECEIVE-THE-POSTED-JSON
```

Details on https://docs.platform.sh/administration/integrations/webhooks.html